# How to reconnect an edge between nodes and get the maximum possible size?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, dijkstra

There is a graph. You can look at first picture. The graph is not directed and let's say that distance between nodes is always `1` here. However, distance can be different.
So, the path of maximum length here is between the most left and the most right nodes and equals to `3 = 1 + 1 + 1`

[image]

I am allowed to move **only one edge** between nodes in such way that I can get longer maximum path in the graph. Look at second picture:

[image]

So, the length has became `5 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`

The goal is to move an edge and get the longest maximum path in the graph.

**Please, pay attention on circled up lines between nodes. They're not edges! I just wanted to show how to traverse the graph for getting the maximum length!**

I should say that input data is

```
{length_1, from_node_1, to_node_1}
{length_2, from_node_2, to_node_2}
{length_3, from_node_3, to_node_3}
...
{length_N, from_node_N, to_node_N}
```

What an algorithm should I use? I cannot do that with brute force because after moving one edge I should look for maximum path again and start from each node but the amount of nodes is about `2000`...

Comment: Going from the first to the second picture, you definitely moved more than one edge, and created a couple new ones too... Edit: ah wait, the curved ones aren't supposed to be edges, they indicate the longest path :)

Comment: It's an interesting question, but why is this tagged `dynamic-programming`? Do you know or suspect that a DP solution exists?

Comment: Given that the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is NP-complete, an efficient exact solution to this cannot exist. If your graph is always a tree, like in the example, I expect it can be done in polynomial time. For non-tree graphs, you could develop an approximation algorithm.

Comment: @Thomas sorry! Circled edges are not edges! I wanted to show the path in this way :( real edges are straight

Comment: Btw I have a good idea. I should run over all edges. Cut an edge. Then I get two subgraphs. I need to find the maximum lengths in two subgraphs and add length of the cut edge. It'll be O(N^2)

Comment: Do you have to keep the graph connected? Does a disconnection imply an infinite max distance?

Comment: @Dave are you talking about a commentary above? Disconnection doesn't mean anything. Disconnection creates two separated graphs and that's it :)

Comment: If cutting any edge results in two connected components, then you have a tree, not a graph in general. This is important to mention in your question, because it permits more efficient solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've found a good method to solve this problem without brute force. As I mentioned above in commentaries, I tried this:

1. Try to remove an edge from a set of given edges;
2. Try to build two subgraphs. There is a rupture between two subgraphs because of removed edge.
3. Try to find diameters `d1, d2` of two subgraphs `G1, G2`
4. Get the length `Li = d1 + d2 + length_of_removed_edge`
5. Go to point `1` and repeat this for another edge. Get `Li+1`
6. After running this loop, choose maximum among `Li` -- this is solution